# how to interpret correlation coefficient at baseline and after the cognitive test

Tags: correlation, interpretation

I am testing the association between two HRV parameters and memory cognitive test. I computed Pearson’s correlation using R and I just dont know how to interpret the differences at baseline and duringthe test.. I would really appreciate any help
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- You have correlations of up to -0.4, but p-values of > .16. This shows us that you have fewer than 15 data points, so you're only going to be able to detect extremely large correlations. If you're not expecting to find extremely large correlations (and you never find large correlations between physiology and cognitive task-based parameters), don't even bother looking.
- All you can say from this data is there is no significant correlation for each parameter, at either time point.

Comment: Thanks! and yes it's a very small dataset!